# Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable with multiple IDs in a variable not working

Tags: powershell, event-log

This work for me:

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{Logname = "ForwardedEvents" ; ID = 4625,4740}
```

(.... results I expect...)

This works:

```
$EventId = "4625"

Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{Logname = "ForwardedEvents" ; ID = $EventId}
```

This doesn't work:

```
$EventId = "4625,4740"

Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{Logname = "ForwardedEvents" ; ID = $EventId}
```

Error...

```
  Get-WinEvent : No events were found that match the specified selection criteria.
At line:1 char:13
+ Get-WinEvent <<<<  -FilterHashTable @{Logname = "ForwardedEvents" ; ID = $EventIds}
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-WinEvent], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchingEventsFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWinEventCommand
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just change it to `$EventId = 4625,4740` (remove the quotes) and that should work. Looking at the [documentation for `Get-WinEvent` and the `-FilterHashTable`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849682.aspx) we see:

> ```
> -- ID=<Int32[]>
> ```

So it is expecting an array and not a string.

Comment: Thanks Matt.  Works great.